# Does (or can) the PostgreSQL `COPY TO` command guarantee a particular row order?

Tags: sql, postgresql, copy, export-to-csv

I know that PostgreSQL 9 allows the `COPY (SELECT ...) ...` syntax, but I need a solution that is PostgreSQL 7 compatible.

E.g., does the `COPY TO` command output data in the order it was written to the table, or does it use a particular index (or the primary key)?

Comment: Why on *earth* would you be using PostgreSQL 7.anything? The improvements since then are huge, and some of them (removal of fsm_pages for example, or the autovacuum improvements) quite important.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the underlying problem you are trying to solve here. Why do you need to know this / do this? What is the concern with the ordering of the output, what makes it relevant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`COPY` reads the table linearly, page-by-page, from the start of the physical table to the end.

If the table was created with `COPY` or with a series of `INSERT`s without any `UPDATE`s or `DELETE`s then that'll be the order it was written in - though PostgreSQL does not guarantee this, and the order of a table is technically undefined.

If you need to generate ordered CSV-like output from an ancient PostgreSQL, I suggest having an external program (say, a Python + `psycopg2` script) connect and do a `SELECT ... ORDER BY`, read the results, transform them into the desired format, and write them to an output file.

Another option, though it isn't guaranteed to work, is to `CLUSTER` the origin input table on the desired sort key. This will rewrite the table into the desired physical order, which `COPY` will then emit when scanning the table.

By far the best option is not to use a prehistoric fossil version of PostgreSQL in the first place.

*Edit after explanation in comments*:

You don't need `COPY` at all, just a vaguely efficient extract tool/script. You could use any existing ETL tool (Pentaho Kettle, Talend Studio, CloverETL, etc), or just a trivial script. For speed, even a simple `libpq` program in C if you're keen.

Here's a trivial Python example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import psycopg2
import csv

csvf = open("csv.out","wb")
csvw = csv.writer(csvf, dialect='excel-tab')

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=regress")
curs = conn.cursor()

# Read blocks of 1000 records from the DB
curs.itersize = 1000

curs.execute("SELECT id, name FROM devices ORDER BY id");
csvw.writerow(("id", "name"))
for row in curs:
    csvw.writerow(row)

csvf.close()
```

Of course it's single-threaded, basic, and doesn't figure out the column names automatically, but it gives you the idea. If you want automatic col names, see [psycopg2 dictionary cursors](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html) ... or use something like libpq or PgJDBC that provides all that metadata directly.

A `libpq` version would probably be an hour or two's work.

Comment: (+1) "By far the best option is not to use a prehistoric fossil version of PostgreSQL in the first place". Agreed but unavoidable in many instances.

Comment: @user1420752 Hm, I'd avoid the vendor entirely if they're serious about this kind of thing. What else is unsupported, ancient, insecure or broken in their product? Do they fix bugs in their own code? etc. Vendors need to be pressured to fix issues like this.

Comment: I currently work for "the vendor". Currently. Perhaps that's all I should say. ;)

Comment: @user1420752 Heh. "Currently". Indeed. More seriously, if you need a hand I work for a team that does consulting services for PostgreSQL including helping people with application upgrades. And I know that the 8.3 transition was hard for a lot of people. Though 7, not so much. Anyway, if you're interested see my profile. Otherwise ... good luck?

Comment: @user1420752 What underlying problem are you trying to solve with this anyway? Wanting ordered `COPY` seems like an odd requirement in the first place.

Comment: We have a series of 3rd-party programs that expects a series of fixed-length files as input (not delimited like CSV), but they produce inconsistent results when the rows aren't ordered. I need to fix this. We currently extract and format the rows with an in-house Kylix program. The output file is 12MB in size, yet the program uses over 8GB of RAM (and 3GB of swap) and crashes when trying to pull out ~50,000 rows (~250 bytes per row). The existing programs can't be modified, so I was just going to try `psql -c "COPY... DELIMITER ','" | sort -t, -k2,2n | tab2fix > final_file.dat`.

Comment: 1. We can't modify the 3rd party programs. 2. The original developers of the in-house Kylix program have left. 3. The suggestion has been made to rewrite the in-house program in C++. 4. We only have 5 clients running PG7, the rest have been moved to PG9, but thank you for your offer.

Comment: @user1420752 In that case, see edit above. It's trivial to write your own extractor, one that doesn't require gigs of RAM, or you can use any number of 3rd party ETL tools.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The C++ alternative will be a drop-in replacement  (using libpq, which I'm quite familiar with), and it has to support a dozen or so command-line switches and it requires a lot of testing, meaning it's going to be more like 2 days work rather than 2 hours.

Comment: "If the table was created with COPY or with a series of INSERTs without any UPDATEs or DELETEs then that'll be the order it was written in - though PostgreSQL does not guarantee this."  Can you explain what is meant by this?  The first statement sounds like a guarantee.

Comment: @dsaxton It means that it works that way right now, at least in most cases, but there could be exceptions and it could change in some future version without notice. It is not a documented, guaranteed behaviour. If you find a case where it doesn't behave that way in a current Pg version it won't be treated as a bug, since we never promised to work that way in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe `COPY TO` guarantees any sort of order (the 7.4 doc does not mention any ordering, so I would not rely on it being consistent -- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/sql-copy.html). Much like a `SELECT` on a table **without** an `ORDER BY` clause may often output rows in order by their primary key, but it isn't guaranteed.

The doc for `SELECT` says this (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/sql-select.html):

> If the ORDER BY clause is specified, the returned rows are sorted in
>   the specified order. If ORDER BY is not given, the rows are returned
>   in whatever order the system finds fastest to produce.

I suspect it is much the same for `COPY TO` without any `SELECT`.

If you cannot use the `COPY (SELECT ...)` form due to backwards compatibility needs, the 
 most straightforward option that comes to mind is to:

1. Create the *destination* table with no *indexes* nor *primary key constraint*
2. Add one of those after doing the `COPY` -- in the same transaction -- to enforce the desired ordering.